# Rewrite Maps in IIS Make web.config Too Large

Tags: iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I am migrating a website which is/will be running on IIS and I will be using rewrite maps to 301 redirect old ".asp" URLs to a new style of URL. For many thousands of URLs there is no pattern, so it appears I must rely on rewrite maps.

My problem is that the default web.config size limit is 250kb, and in my environment, I don't have access to change this (as can be done at the registry level - if one had access).

I have looked into moving the rewriteMaps section to an external file, but the external files also have the default size limit of 250kg, so this is also not going to work.

I am looking for some other way to handle this...  I am sitting at 242kb currently and have over twice the amount of old to new redirect mapping to add.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find solution to this problem?

Comment: @KristapsVilerts - Unfortunately no... I filled up the map to capicity with the highest-trafficked redirects (so they would be fastest) and all of the remainder went into a REDIRECTS table in the db... SO, after the request passes all of the rewrite rules in the file, it defaults to a certain script. One of the first things that script does is check the REDIRECTS table, and if an entry exists, I do a redirect in the code... it's slower, but most of the stuff in the table is long tail, and as I said, the most visited redirects are still in the file.

Comment: sad to hear that. We are using SharePoint and found workaround - redirecting all incoming requests to custom ASHX control, where we made custom incoming request redirect logic (without limitations).

Comment: Yep, what you did is basically a different implementation of the same workaround that I did. Still would love a way around it as a redirect at the  IIS level is much faster than going to the DB, checking, and then redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am in a shared environment, there was no solution other than to move it to a single external config file, which was again, limited to 250KB.

So here is what I did:

I filled up the map to capicity **with the highest-trafficked redirects** and of course any groups of urls that could be redirected using a pattern (so they would be fastest).

For the 100k remaining long-tail of the redirects, I put them into a REDIRECTS table in the db... SO, after the request passes all of the rewrite rules in the file (and of course, doesn't hit any), it defaults the request to a certain script. One of the first things the script does is check the REDIRECTS table, and if an entry exists, I do a redirect in the code... it's slower, but most of the stuff in the table is long tail, and as I said, the most visited redirects are still in the file. This has worked well for me so far, and I can add as many redirects as I want... e.g. if a page title/url gets edited, my admin area automatically adds the redirect, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Nativerd.dll file uses the value of this registry key to determine the maximum allowed size, in KB, of the Web.config files. The Configuration system assumes a default value of 250 KB in Windows Server 2008 and 100 KB in the release version of Windows Vista.

The reason for the 250KB limit is to reduce attacks for uploading a large web.config file. You can change the the limit by altering the upper value in your registry:

```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB (REG_DWORD)
```

See: [Description of the registry keys that are used by IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954864)

Another option is to split your web.config files into multiple smaller files.

Comment: In my question, I specifically said I can not edit the registry, so that is not an option, and I also noted that i have already moved rewriteMaps to an external file, but that it also has the 250kb limit problem, so this answer does not help and does not answer the question. Perhaps you just dropped in any answer for a chance to get the bounty. :(

Answer (score 0):

We were stuck on this for a long while, we ended up writing our own 301 redirector. In sitecore it was in a pipeline patched after ItemResolver which consumes the large file (not included in any Web.configs). We could not use the "registry hack" option as it an Azure Service App and there is no (easy and cheap) access to the registry.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing as well. Got as much bulk stuff in the web.config files as I could (as it's faster), and anything beyond that gets looked up in a redirect dictionary. Sucks but was only option in an environment when I can't work with the registry.

Answer (score -3):

You can split up your configuration into a few different files as Neill said.

You will have a main web.config file in which you’ll reference sub config files by adding a configSource attribute onto the sections you would like to split into other files.

For example, if you’d like to split the section “appsettings” in another file, you would change the appSettings section in your web.config file to :

```
<appSettings configSource="appsettings.config" />
```

and in the appsettings.config file, you would add all your appsettings entries like they were in the original web.config file, for example;

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:RestrictXmlControls" value="true" />
     <add key="FeedCacheTime" value="300" />
     <add key="FeedPageUrl" value="/_layouts/15/feed.aspx?" />
     <add key="FeedXsl1" value="/Style Library/Xsl Style Sheets/Rss.xsl" />
     <add key="aspnet:AllowAnonymousImpersonation" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

Obviously with the rewrite maps instead.

Comment: In my question,I noted that i have already moved rewriteMaps to an external file, but that it also has the 250kb limit problem, so this answer does not help and does not answer the question. As far as I can tell, it is not possible to have more than one external rewriteMaps file.